JFileChooser title icon not changing
I have seen answers saying that the icon is taken from the parent, but it is not working for me.
I have a JDialog class where I set the Icon:
this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass() .getClassLoader().getResource("Icons/favicon.png")));
I load it this way because I will use a Jar.
This is how I initialize the FileChooser:
fc = new MyFileChooser();
this is the constructor of the MyFileChooser class:
public MyFileChooser() {
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "Archivo wav (*.wav)", "wav");
        this.setDialogTitle("Elige la cancion a añadir");
        this.setFileFilter(filter);
        this.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    }

And this is how I show the FileChooser when clicking on a button:
if (chooseFileButton == e.getSource()) {
  // got it from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java
  int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
}

I though 'this' refers to the Dialog class.
Edit: I have also tried 'AddDialog.this' being AddDialog the name of the class for the JDialog

Is your file chooser extending something? Maybe you should call super first?

MyFileChooser is extending of JFileChooser, when I call the showOpenDialog, it calls the parent, the only modifications I have done to the class are those that are shown in the constructor. In the constructor, I have tried to call the super and nothing changed either

Here is a complete example that works on Windows. I showed the file dialog inside of an action listener, so I had to use the outter classname with this, Worms.this
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Worms extends JFrame{
        public void buildGui(){
                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.fillOval(0, 0, 64, 64);
                g2d.dispose();
                setIconImage( img );
                JButton click = new JButton("click");
                click.addActionListener( evt ->{
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                        int value = chooser.showOpenDialog(Worms.this);
                });


                add(click);
                pack();
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                setVisible(true);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            new Worms().buildGui();

        }

}

Maybe you can check that since it is complete, compilable. Your problem could be an OS/JVM quirk so you might have to include more information.

Maybe my problem resides in the way I give the param to the JFileChooser? since my JFileChooser is 'inside' the JDialog, instead of 'this' I need to give something else?

@tumorito You need to pass it a reference to the Frame with the icon changed.

It was my fault, I was executing it in eclipse, running a specific configuration and it was pointing to another project, so the changes I was making werent displayed :) my mistake. I will leave this as the marked answer as this is the correct thing. Thank you for the fast response

Ill update it to show using the name of the outter class to reference this.
